# Spraying using masking tape

Tags: paint

All,

I’m quite experienced as a classic bike restorer but have never tried painting before. I’ve started the job and am absolutely loving the preparation stage. One problem I foresee, however, is completing the tank respray, which is a candy coat (translucent red over silver) with a distinctive black cross running along the spine of the tank and down the sides. To achieve this, I intend spraying the tank black, then masking out the form of the cross, before applying first the silver and then the red ‘candy’ coat. I assume that when I remove the masking tape, there will be a lip at the transition from black to red. I intend pin-lining the join which, presumably is a way of disguising the lip, but I would prefer to do the line along a completely flat transition. Would I achieve this by the use of wet and dry; if so, what grade? I ought to add that I then intend lacquering the tank.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the positive and negative for the shape then the second coat matches the thickness of the first - as long as you apply the same amount on both passes.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes. so instead of spraying then masking out, I’d mask out both shapes. And if the total candy coat is 4 layers (passes), that is, two base, two top coats, the black cross needs to be 4 layers (passes)? I could then do one layer of lacquer, fix my transfers and add the pin-stripe, then a final lacquer....